# Loading a Different WordPress Theme Based on Visitor's Geographic Location?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, geotargetting

I've been searching all over the web for a solution that would allow for a WordPress based website to load specific already translated themes based on a users geographic location across the globe.  Does anyone know if a plugin or some sort of code exists to handle something such as this?

Ideally, I'd like to keep the domain constant and just have the correctly translated theme load dependent upon the visitor's location.  I would be using another plugin to show/hide specific posts and content dependent upon the visitor's location; however, this doesn't solve my problem with the actual site being translated.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: [This may help](http://wordpress.org/plugins/geographical-redirect/).

Comment: Sweet! I'll check this out and see if it'll work.  My guess is that a plugin such as this would be used AFTER you've got the various translated sites ready.  I'm assuming this won't translate the site language for you.

Comment: RCV, do you think this method would work so we can have only one blog site, rather than building individual ones based upon a specific country/language?  I'm just trying to find the most efficient way to do this and I'm not a highly experienced coder, but know my way around.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I think this is the right way and this plugin will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i think changing the theme completely is not possible, but what you can do is to track the geo-location by any API, and change your css according to it.

Comment: It's possible using [template_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect), to load a different template.